# compress image size on upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to compress an image on upload using CodeIgniter.

When I'm trying to upload an image larger than 200 kb in size then it should compress the image size on upload image in CodeIgniter.

This is `controller.php`, ie `college_panel`:

```
        public function college_logo($collg_id='')
        {   
            $this->data['active']='manage_logo';
            if($this->session->userdata("user_login")){
            if($this->input->post()){
                $config['upload_path']='./uploads/college_logo';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
                $data1['img_name']  = $_FILES['logo_img']['name'];
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('logo_img'))
                 {
            $upload_error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     echo "<script>alert('College Logo upload successfully...');</script>";
                      $this->session->set_flashdata('College Logo upload successfully', 'updated');
                 }
                $data['collg_id']=$this->input->post('collg_id');
                $data['logo_img']=$data1['img_name'];
                $row=0;
                if($row==0)
                {
            $result1=$this->front->update_table('tbl_college',array('collg_id'=>$collg_id),$data); 

                }   
            }
             $result=$this->front->get_data_where('tbl_college',array('collg_id'=>$collg_id));
                 $data['result']=$result; 
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
            $data['password']=$this->input->post('password');
            $data['isactive']=1;
            $old_data=$this->front->get_data_where('tbl_login',array('isactive'=>1));
            $data['old_data']=$old_data;
            $record=$this->front->get_data_where('tbl_college',array('collg_id'=>$collg_id));
            $data['record']=$record[0];
            $this->load->view('collg_admin/header',$data,$this->data);
            $this->load->view('collg_admin/logo',$data);
            }
            else
            {

            redirect(base_url().'login');
          }
     }
```

This is view code ie `logo.php`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default upload">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h2>College Logo</h2></div>
      <br><br>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <center>
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <?php if (isset($result[0]->logo_img) && !empty($result[0]->logo_img)) { ?>
            <img class=" img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/college_logo/<?php echo $result[0]->logo_img;?>" height="200" width="200"><br>
            <?php } else {?>
              <img style="" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/default_logo.png" height="200" width="600"><br>
             <!-- <p>College Logo are not available.</p>-->
              <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </center>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>access/college_panel/college_logo/<?php echo $result[0]->collg_id;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
        <!--   <?php //print_r($result);?>-->
            <input type="hidden" name="collg_id" id="id_hh" value="<?php echo $result[0]->collg_id;?>" autofocus="" class="form-control" style="width: 100px;" >
              <br><br>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" name="logo_img" value="<?php  echo $result[0]->logo_img; ?> " required/><br>
              <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="">Submit</button>

              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

How to compress the image on upload?

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['upload_path'] = './upload/';  
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';  
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);  
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))  
            {  
                 echo $this->upload->display_errors();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 $data = $this->upload->data();  
                 $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';  
                 $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["file_name"];  
                 $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;  
                 $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;  
                 $config['quality'] = '60%';  
                 $config['width'] = 200;  
                 $config['height'] = 200;  
                 $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.$data["file_name"];  
                 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
                 $this->image_lib->resize();  
                 $this->load->model('main_model');  
                 $image_data = array(  
                      'name'          =>     $data["file_name"]  
                      );  
                 $this->main_model->insert_image($image_data);  
                 echo $this->main_model->fetch_image();  
                 //echo '<img src="'.base_url().'upload/'.$data["file_name"].'" width="300" height="225" class="img-thumbnail" />';  
            }
```