# compress the image on upload codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is controller.php ie college_panel

```
public function college_logo($collg_id = '')
{
    $this->data['active'] = 'manage_logo';
    if ($this->session->userdata("user_login")) {
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/college_logo';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
            $data1['img_name']       = $_FILES['logo_img']['name'];
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('logo_img')) {
                $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('College Logo upload successfully...');</script>";
                $this->session->set_flashdata('College Logo upload successfully', 'updated');
            }
            $data['collg_id'] = $this->input->post('collg_id');
            $data['logo_img'] = $data1['img_name'];
            $row              = 0;
            if ($row == 0) {
                $result1 = $this->front->update_table('tbl_college', array('collg_id' => $collg_id), $data);

            }
        }
        $result           = $this->front->get_data_where('tbl_college', array('collg_id' => $collg_id));
        $data['result']   = $result;
        $data['email']    = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
        $data['isactive'] = 1;
        $old_data         = $this->front->get_data_where('tbl_login', array('isactive' => 1));
        $data['old_data'] = $old_data;
        $record           = $this->front->get_data_where('tbl_college', array('collg_id' => $collg_id));
        $data['record']   = $record[0];
        $this->load->view('collg_admin/header', $data, $this->data);
        $this->load->view('collg_admin/logo', $data);
    } else {

        redirect(base_url() . 'login');
    }
}
```

this is view code ie logo.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default upload">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h2>College Logo</h2>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php if (isset($result[0]->logo_img) && !empty($result[0]->logo_img)) {?>
                        <img class=" img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/college_logo/<?php echo $result[0]->logo_img; ?>" height="200" width="200"><br>
                        <?php } else {?>
                        <img style="" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/default_logo.png" height="200" width="600"><br>
                        <!-- <p>College Logo are not available.</p>-->
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">
                    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>access/college_panel/college_logo/<?php echo $result[0]->collg_id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!--   <?php //print_r($result);?>-->
                            <input type="hidden" name="collg_id" id="id_hh" value="<?php echo $result[0]->collg_id; ?>" autofocus="" class="form-control" style="width: 100px;">
                            <br><br>
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" name="logo_img" value="<?php echo $result[0]->logo_img; ?> " required /><br>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to compress image on upload using codeigniter .when i m trying to upload more then 200 kb image size or mor then 200 then it hsould compress the image size on upload image in codeigniter.how to compress the image on upload of image. i just want to compress the image of the file using codeigniter if need more code will help you

Comment: check your previous added question from another stackoverflow id

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808257/compress-image-size-on-upload-in-codeigniter, posted under a different user account.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and stop posting “I want” as a question - that isn’t one. Explain what you researched and tried so far, and describe what the specific problem you are facing is.